# If $ f(x) = x^3+\frac{3x}{4}-\frac{3x^2}{2}+\frac{7}{8}.$ Then $ \int^{\frac{3}{4}}_{\frac{1}{4}}f(f(x))dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> If $\displaystyle f(x) = x^3+\frac{3x}{4}-\frac{3x^2}{2}+\frac{7}{8}.$ Then $\displaystyle \int^{\frac{3}{4}}_{\frac{1}{4}}f(f(x))dx$

Try: Given $\displaystyle f(x) =x^3+\frac{3x}{4}-\frac{3x^2}{2}+\frac{7}{8}. $

Then $\displaystyle f(1-x) = (1-x)^3+\frac{3}{4}(1-x)-\frac{3}{2}(1-x)^2+\frac{7}{8}$

$$f(1-x) = -x^3+\frac{3x^2}{2}-\frac{3x}{4}+\frac{9}{8}$$

$$f(x)+f(1-x) = 2$$

Let $$I = \int^{\frac{3}{4}}_{\frac{1}{4}}f(f(x))dx = \int^{\frac{3}{4}}_{\frac{1}{4}}f(f(1-x))dx$$

I did not understand how to solve from there

could some help me to solve it

Comment: I mean, is there much to be said about this? Just compute $f(f(x))$ and then compute the integral.

Comment: Notice $$f(x) = \left(x-\frac12\right)^3 + 1\implies f(f(x)) = \left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^3 + \frac12\right)^3 + 1$$
Change variable to $u = x - \frac12$, the integral becomes

$$\int_{-\frac14}^\frac14 \left[\left(u^3 + \frac12\right)^3 + 1\right] du
\stackrel{\color{red}{\text{WHY?}}}{=} 2\int_0^\frac14 \left[\frac32 u^6 + \frac98\right] du = \cdots
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Note that $$f(x)={(x-{1\over 2})^3}+1$$and $$\int^{\frac{3}{4}}_{\frac{1}{4}}f(f(x))dx=\int^{\frac{1}{4}}_{-\frac{1}{4}}f(f(u+{1\over 2}))du=\int^{\frac{1}{4}}_{-\frac{1}{4}}f(u^3+1)du$$